# Proof verification for function property

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

May I have a proof verification?

Suppose$f:A \rightarrow B$.Let $C,C_1,C_2$ be subsets of $A$ and $D,D_1,D_2$ be subsets of $B$.

Prove $f^{-1}(B\setminus D)=A\setminus f^{-1}(D)$

Attempt

Let $x \in f^{-1}(B\setminus D)$ then $f(x) \in B$ and $f(x) \notin D$

Thus $x \in f^{-1}(B) \subseteq A$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(D)$ so $x \in A \setminus f^{-1}(D)$

Now suppose

$x \in A \setminus f^{-1}(D)$

thus $x \in A$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(D)$

Then $f(x) \in f(A) \subseteq B$ and $f(x) \notin D$

so $f(x) \in B \setminus D$

And $x \in f^{-1}(B \setminus D)$

Comment: Your proof is is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner.

x in f$^{-1}$(B - D) iff
f(x) in B - D iff
f(x) in B, f(x) not in D iff
x in A, x not in f$^{-1}$(D) iff
x in A - f$^{-1}$(D).

A direct version of this proposition is
f$^{-1}$(D$^c$) = (f$^{-1}$(D))$^c.$